# Filter a list of objects based on a parameter

Tags: c#, oop, generics

```
class Officer
{
    Person person;
}

class Person
{
    string name;
}
```

Suppose I've a list of Officer and a list of Person. I want to filter these two list based on some criteria.

So I wrote this method:

```
public List<Person> filterName(List<Person> list)
{
   // some filter logic
}
```

And I'm using this method for the two lists in the following way:

```
main()
{
     ...
     List<Officer> officers = Initialize();
     List<Person> validNames= filterNames(officers.Select(o=>o.person.name).ToList())
     foreach (var officer in officers)
     {
          if (!validNames.Contains(officer.Person.name))
                 officers.remove(officer);
     }
     // finally I have a valid set of officers here

     List<Person> persons = Initialize();
     var filteredPersons = filterNames(persons.Select(o=>o.name).ToList())
}
```

Is there a good way to use generics so I can avoid the following code in the main method()?

```
 List<string> validNames = filterNames(officers.Select(o=>o.fullName).ToList())
 foreach (var officer in officers)
 {
      if (!validNames.Contains(officer.name))
             officers.remove(officer);
 }
```

And use generics somehow to update the officers list using generics.

Comment: You don't have a question in there, what are you asking?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before I wrote the question. Let me know if it's not clear enough

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you are looking for, you can make a generic "filter" by using something like `public List<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, bool> filter) { ... }` but at that point you might as well just do that in the LINQ statement, like `persons.Where(o => o.Length < 10).ToList()`...

Comment: foreach (var officer in officers)
     {
          if (!validNames.Contains(officer.fullName.name))
                 officers.remove(officers);
     }

     foreach (var person in persons)
     {
          if (!validNames.Contains(person.name))
                 persons.remove(person);
     }

Can I have these two for loops inside the generic method somehow?

Comment: Like @RonBeyer says: are you just looking for Enumerable.Where?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - I can see that this slightly different semantically, but realistically, if you don't a critical performance issue, you can use Where and ToList to make a new list instead of removing from the original.

Comment: The `List` is passed by reference, you can remove items in the generic method if you want.

Comment: Wait. I'll try to update the question - I think I'm not able to explain the question clearly here

Comment: Updated. Is this more clear? Apologies with my English

Comment: I'm still at a loss for what the problem with `officers = officers.Where(o => ...).ToList()` is - is there something else with a reference to the original list that requires it to be updated?

Comment: I want to avoid writing a for loop to remove officers from the officers list. Can I use generics somehow? (Just need to update the officers list)

Comment: Check updated answer, think it has what you're looking for?

Comment: The search criteria is a bit complex. It calls a sproc which returns a list of persons. So I cannot check the way you've mentioned. Can you have a look at the updates @mariocatch

Comment: You can create your own method that takes a `Predicate<Officer>`, and does whatever logic you need, and pass that into `RemoveAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's assume you have some complicated `FilterNames` function that operates on a list, and your goal is to filter out based on some `Person` criteria. I would rewrite the filter like this:

```
public bool FilterPerson(Person p)
{
    //Some complicated logic
    //Returns true if person should be kept
    //Returns false if the person should be rejected
}
```

Now you can use that in a Linq statement:

```
var officers = Initialize().Where(o => FilterPerson(o.Person)).ToList();
```

No need to remove items from the list. You could still use the interim object, it just requires an additional step:

```
var officers = Initialize();    //Returns List<Officer>
var filteredOfficers = officers.Where(o => FilterPerson(o.Person)).ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect! This is awesome! Thanks @Ron

Comment: Do you have recommendations for learning generics/ linq statement?

Comment: [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/index.htm) has some decent tutorials,

Comment: var filteredOfficers = officers.Where(o => FilterPerson(o.Person)).ToList(); isn't right. Expects a list of persons but passes a single one

Comment: @Raj `FilterPerson` in my example takes a single person, not a list.

Answer (score 3):

New answer based on recent edits:

```
var officers = new List<Officer>
{
    new Officer { Name = "Officer Foo" },
    new Officer { Name = "Officer Bar" }
};

officers.RemoveAll(o => o.Name.Contains("Bar"));
// Officers now only contains "Officer Foo"
```

------------ *Old answer here* ----------------

Can you use OOP here and derive `Person` and `Officer` from something in common?

If so, then you can easily take their common property and filter on that instead of writing two separate pieces of logic to deal with each of them.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var officers = new List<Officer>
    {
        new Officer { Name = "Officer Foo" },
        new Officer { Name = "Officer Bar" }
    };

    var workers = new List<Worker>
    {
        new Worker { Name = "Worker Foo" },
        new Worker { Name = "Worker Bar" }
    };

    var people = workers.Cast<IPerson>().Concat(officers);
    var filteredPeople = Program.Filter(people, "Foo");

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

static IEnumerable<IPerson> Filter(IEnumerable<IPerson> people, string keyword)
{
    return people.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(keyword));
}

interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Officer : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Worker : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Persons and Officers are not related - they just happen to have a name field which is common. Appreciate the thought though